# How to re-enable network adapter in a VM after disabling it in vSphere?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vsphere, disconnect, network-connection

I disabled the network adapter to a VM in vSphere by going to edit settings then unchecking the "connected" box next to Network adapter 1, and now it won't let me re-enable it, so the VM has no network access. When I recheck the box, it just becomes unchecked again. Within the VM itself, it says "A network cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken."

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of vSphere are you using? What is the vSphere client - Flash, HTML, desktop? It's possible that this is a bug with the UI. Did you try to use the API to re-enable it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed to fix it by reverting to a previous snapshot. Not an ideal solution, but it works.